# In jest frame work describe function call before any test

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I am using Jest framework `(version 23.3.0)(node version 6.9.4)` to test the javascript code, 
where I have a test named `'update board name'`. I need to update board name 
based on the boards ids which I am fetching in `'getBoards Ids'` test.
my problem here is describe gets called before the test `'getBaords Ids'`.
so test `'update board name'` never get called because length of boardIds array is 0.

```
let boardIds=[];

test('getBoard Ids',()=>{
 //calling api to get board ids
})

describe('boards test',()=>{
for(let i=0;i<=boardIds.length;i++){

    test('update board name',()=>{
           // calling API to update the board name using ids from boardIds array.
        })
    })

}
});
});
```

We have hooks to run some code before and after the test but do we have any hook   which can called before describe?

Comment: you should keep each test block independent. that is the point of unit tests.

Comment: @DanielA.White i agree, but i need to run this test multiple time. to make it independent i can write this test in a function.